# Learning Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I am a PL/SQL developer and new to Java. Planning to learn ADF to develop an intranet web application with dashbords and entry forms. Do I need to learn Java language to get the maximum out of ADF ? Where should I start?

Answer (score 3):

> Where should I start?

- Visit the [ADFInsiderEssentials](https://www.youtube.com/user/ADFInsiderEssentials) on YouTube. There are plenty of great videos about ADF, like [Introduction to Oracle ADF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMPGSCAmnzI&list=PLAHRwp0XMMCky20UnNBM9AEyPMbaECCbC).
- You might also get a book like  the [Oracle JDeveloper 11g Handbook: A Guide to Fusion Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071602380), but I personally find this one too much focused on where you have to click in JDeveloper, without explaining what really happens in the background. In my opinion, a better alternative is [Oracle ADF Real World Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849684820).
- Then, download JDeveloper from [JDeveloper downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) and get started - you *will* need to try out the samples from the videos and books and see how they work in reality.
- Plan some time to get started - ADF is a huge framework, and it takes a considerable amount of time to get familiar with it.
- There is also the [Google+ ADF community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/113990885678873525746)

> Do I need to learn Java language to get the maximum out of ADF ?

Yes. ADF is based on J2EE and unless you implement some very trivial application (which would be possible purely declaratively through the JDeveloper user interface), you will need to get started with Java.

Comment: That's really a good explanation. Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Here is some link I think it will help you in your learning process.

[Oracle Application Development Framework - Oracle ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html)

[Series of presentations will take you through the basics of learning Oracle's ADF](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAHRwp0XMMCky20UnNBM9AEyPMbaECCbC)

[Learn ADF in Steps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/learnadf-082417.html)

[ADF Code Corner Articles](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/index-101235.html#CodeCornerSamples)

Comment: Thanks for these useful links @Salman